# How to check if a user account is locked via PHP/LDAP?

Tags: php, ldap

We've created an intranet site that requires the same password as the user's network login, so we use LDAP to check the username/password.

That's fine, but if they enter it incorrectly three times it locks their account out, and one or two users have found this confusing.

Is there anyway at all I could check, using LDAP/PHP whether or not their account is locked, so I can display a little message prompting them to contact IT?

Comment: How do they login if their account is locked out?

Comment: What LDAP are your running?  I don't think "locked" is a standard property of a user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect to the LDAP using the LDAP functions in PHP and perform search/read to locate and get the information. You can read about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

Find a sample code for reading entries:

```
if (!($ldap=ldap_connect($ldapip, $ldapport)))  
    {
        die("Error:Unable to connect to the LDAP Server");
        return;
    }
    if (!ldap_bind($ldap, $admindn, $adminpwd))
    {
        die("Error:Unable to bind to '$dn'!");
        return;
    }
    
    $sr=ldap_search($ldap, $userbasedn, $filter);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);
    
    if($info["count"] > 0)
    {
        $entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap, $sr);
        $return_array = ldap_get_attributes($ldap, $entry);
        if($return_array)
        {
            for ($i=0;$i<$return_array['count'];$i++)
            {
                      print($return_array[$i]);
                      print($return_array[$return_array[$i]][0]);
                    }
        }
    }
```

You might want to check for the fields lockoutTime in AD, nsaccountlock in LDAP and read them

Comment: lockedByIntruder in eDirectory.  I forget the reset time attribute name though.

Answer (score 2):

One of AD profile attribute `useraccountcontrol`.
This contains `decimal` value which can be converted into readable here;

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144
- http://ananthdeodhar.com/php-active-directory-integration-get-useraccountcontrol-attributes/

Locked can be referring to multiple cases, normally

- `ACCOUNTDISABLE` 2 / 0x0002 (hexa)
- `PASSWORD_EXPIRED` 8388608  / 0x800000
- `LOCKOUT` 16 / 0x0010

Answer (score 0):

Without a standard "lockout" field I would use an LDAP browser to compare an account before and after a lockout.  You can use [LBE](http://www.openchannelfoundation.org/orders/index.php?group_id=9) (LDAP Browser/Edit) to extract LDIF files of a user object and then use your favorite diff tool to compare them.

Comment: When did LBE go to a 'for-fee' model?  I was wondering where it went, since all the links I had to it, were dead.  

Geez.  My favorite LDAP browser still...

Comment: No idea... I didn't even notics that part.  (I havn't used it in over a year)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't that defeat the idea of having a shared logon?

If your intranet site allows more trials than the network login, it can be used to find the password for a user.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022 and this is still a relevant question. I had to code similar logic to query an Active Directory and find out if a user account is locked. The accepted answer didn't really help me. Here is a sample code that worked for me:

```
function isAccountLocked($ldapconn, $userDn)
{
    $read = ldap_read($ldapconn, $userDn, "(objectclass=*)", array("msds-user-account-control-computed")) or die("Not found");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $read);
    $attributeValue = 0;
    if (array_key_exists("0", $info)) {
        if (array_key_exists("msds-user-account-control-computed", $info["0"])) {
            if (array_key_exists("0", $info["0"]["msds-user-account-control-computed"])) {
                $attributeValue = $info["0"]["msds-user-account-control-computed"]["0"];
            }
        }
    }
    return $attributeValue == 16 || $attributeValue == 8388608; 
    //16 - Account locked (by many unsuccessful login attempts)
    //8388608 - Password Expired
    //2 - Account disabled -> Not tested.
    //check the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-msds-user-account-control-computed
}
```

Also, you could query `msds-user-account-control-computed` attribute using ldapsearch in Linux terminal.
But, to show it in the result, you *MUST* include msds-user-account-control-computed in the filter. Otherwise, ldapsearch won't return by default.
Check the example below:

```
ldapsearch -x -h activedirectoryhost.example.com -LLL -b "dc=example,dc=com" -D "CN=user,OU=SOME_OU,DC=example,DC=com" "(sAMAccountName=user)" -W cn msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed
```

Surprisingly enough, a powershell query will return a `LockOut` attribute that tells exactly what we want, but other ldap clients won't return it. A sample of powershell query would be as follows:

```
Get-ADUser user -Properties * | Select-Object LockedOut
```

Here are some other usefull links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties#property-flag-descriptions

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/ADSchema/a-msds-user-account-control-computed.md.